# Rxjs import issues in Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I am facing some weird issues while working with Angular 6 and Rxjs 6.
When I import as below

```
Import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/forkJoin';
```

I am getting issue as

[image]
but when I use import as

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/';
```

it works perfectly.

I used the same method to merge operator but when i used import as

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs/';
```

but it thrown error as above and it works fine if i use

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/merge';
```

Could someone point out where is the problem? Why is this working differently?

PS: It's working on reloading page but alternately.

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/concepts/operator-imports.html

Comment: npm install rxjs-compat try this

Comment: Share your TS code

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
 import {merge} from 'rxjs';
```

OR

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Refer: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: 'rxjs', 'rxjs/Rx' packages are blacklisted in my project. So as workaround i am using 'rxjs/' for now. But importing whole 'rxjs' is advisable as it would increase bundle size, right?

Comment: Then you can simply use import { merge } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: check answer again

Comment: if you use single operator it will not increase you bundle size

Comment: i was using the same operator it gave me same issue. so tried static merge method and both produced same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this,

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Check you rxjs version, **it should be 6+**

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bcsl1r

Comment: Originally i had used merge from operators using pipe operator, but it thrown same error.

Comment: which version of rxjs are you using?

Comment: version is 6.0.2