# How to unsubscribe inner observable when source observable completes

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5, rxjs6

I am trying to implement autosave functionality in which i have used switchMap operator within switchMap operator i.e. multiple nested inner observable

```
merge(...eventObservables)
    .pipe(switchMap(({ syncWithServer }) => {
        const source = of(cloneDeep(this.getData()))
            .pipe(tap((data) => this.storageService.storeItem(data.id, {
                data: data,
                synced: false
            })));
        if (syncWithServer) {
            return source.pipe(delay(5 * 1000),
                switchMap((data) =>
                    this.apiService.saveData(data)
                        .pipe(tap(() => this.storageService.storeItem(data.RespondentId, {
                            data: data,
                            synced: true
                        })), tap((response) => response && this.setData(response['Data'], false)))));
        }
        return source;
    }))
```

The problem with above code is API request is completing instead of cancelling when there is new value from eventObservables. Can someone point out what is issue here. As per my understanding when source observable is unsubscribed (As i have used switchMap which will unsubscribe previous observable) switchMap will also unsubscribe inner observable. If i have understood it wrong could someone point out mistake in above code?

Comment: It'll be the delay. The inner switch won't unsubscribe until after the delay. If you want it to unsubscribe before the delay, you could do something like what I've done here: https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc/blob/master/source/operators/switchMapUntil.ts Have a look at the associated spec: https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc/blob/master/source/operators/switchMapUntil-spec.ts#L57-L77

Comment: Thanks @cartant for reply but it still working unchanged.

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible with some mock observables. The inner observables get canceled as expected. Try removing any unrelated detail from your example, e.g. `tap` operators don't affect the behavior unless they throw errors. Also details like `cloneDeep(this.getData())` if they affect the issue provide the code otherwise remove them. Simply do [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi i debugged the code and found issues related to one of my own questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923192/rxjs-import-issues-in-angular-6 Still don't understand why is throwing error by different imports